# Use mention in dialog Slack

Tags: slack-api, mention, slack-dialog

I have developed a slack bot which purpose is to give details about the company's projects.

I tried to use slack dialog to ask for different information such as the name, a description and the people involved in the project.
To do the last part (people involved), I wanted to use mention (@), so that the person who adds the project doesn't have to know the exact name / email of each participants. I'm pretty sure it's not possible but before trying another solution, I wanted to ask since I didn't find anything on internet.

**Can we or can we not use mentions in slack dialog ? And if we can, how ?**

Comment: Do you want to use a single mention or multiple?

Comment: Yes I should have been precise, I want to use multiple mentions, otherwise I would have use the select element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Slack Dialog currently does not have support for multiple mentions. The text elements will has support for url, email, number and telephone number. But not for mentions.

However, mentions work nicely with slash commands. You can add a list of users after your slash command with a mention and their will be automatically detected and matched to list of Slack user.

So maybe its possible for you to start with a slash command including mentions and use the Dialog to request additional information.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but slash commands is not what I'm looking for. I'll use email instead!